# Activating a tab through a javascript call (created from an unordered list)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tabbed menu created through CSS and an HTML unordered list as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjaleel/qt13dzkf/3/). When the link is clicked, I want to scroll down to menu item 2 and make it the selected (active) one. I got the scrolling part down but not sure how to activate the tab.

Could someone please share the Javascript/jQuery to do that?

Here is a snippet of my code, please see the fiddle for the rest..

```
<a>Take me to menu item 3</a>

<div class="container">  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="home" class="active">Home</li>
    <li id="menu1-tab">Menu 1</li>
    <li id="menu2-tab">Menu 2</li>
   <li id="menu3-tab">Menu 3</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script>
$('a').click( function() {
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#menu2-tab').offset().top }, 1500); 
   } ); // how to also activate menu item 2?
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `active` class from all `li`s and add the same class to the `li` you're interested in:

```js
$('a').click( function() {
    
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#menu2-tab').offset().top }, 1500); 
  
  $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(".nav li").eq(2).addClass("active");

} );
```

```css
.nav {
 position: relative;
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.nav li{
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 background-color:#fcfcfc;
 border:solid 1px #e2e2e2;
 height:37px;
 line-height:37px;
 text-align:center;
 color:#aeaeae;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-family: 'latobold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px; 
 margin:0 -2px 0 0;

}

.nav.col3 li {
 width:33.3333%;
 *width:33.2222%;
}

.nav li:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.nav li.active{
 z-index:50;
 font-family: 'latobold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border:solid 1px #e2e2e2;
 border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
 color:#6b7f12;
 background-color:#fff;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>Take me to menu item 3</a> <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
    
    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

<div class="container">

    
    
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="home" class="active">Home</li>
    <li id="menu1-tab">Menu 1</li>
    <li id="menu2-tab">Menu 2</li>
    <li id="menu3-tab">Menu 3</li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

Below is the HTML

```
<a href="#menu2-tab">Take me to menu item 3</a> <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

    Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>
Here is some other content, you can ignore this. <p>

<div class="container">



  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="home" class="active">Home</li>
    <li id="menu1-tab">Menu 1</li>
    <li id="menu2-tab">Menu 2</li>
    <li id="menu3-tab">Menu 3</li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Below is the jquery code for selecting

```
$("a").each(function(){
    var _$this = $(this);
    _$this.click(function(){
        var id = _$this.attr("href");
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(id).offset().top }, 1500);
        $(id).parent().find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(id).addClass("active");
    });
});
```